# broken spark plugs in a 94 Ford Ranger

Tags: ford, sparkplugs, ranger

I broke a spark plug in my 94 Ford Ranger. Everything came out except the threads and the metal casing. The problem I'm having is the easy out will not fit in far enough to grab ahold of the casing with the threads.

Do I need to drill out the tip of the spark plug that is left to allow the easy out to get in deep enough to make a bite? If so, how do I get metal shavings out of the chamber?

I cannot afford to take the truck to a shop. I'm a very poor person and I'm trying to get my truck up and running on my own. I have an easy out set, as well as a torch and general tools.

Comment: Is the piston at the top of the cylinder? This  may be why the easy-out won't bite.

Comment: Any idea why the plugs are so hard to remove? Did you fit them yourself before? If so, it's very important to not tighten them too hard. If you don't have a torque wrench; Screw them in with your hand until you can't, then turn them a quarter turn further with a ratchet. That is enough for new plugs to make a proper gas sealing. Refitting plugs may require more or less force, but you'll get the feel of the needed force by fitting a new plug.

Comment: Additionally, after you've removed stuff with the easy out, you could blow into the plug hole with pressurised air and hope that any stuff that fell in, will come out. Take not that the probe of the air gun must go (deep)into the plug hole to have eny effect.

Answer (score 2):

I am thinking that if the threads are stuck enough for the spark plug to break off, an easy out may not help.

It is not recommended to drill it in place because the shavings will go into the cylinder. It is not likely you would be able to get the shavings out, thus causing another problem altogether.

Unless you can get the treads out without causing damage to the head, I would suggest you remove the head from the engine. That is the only way you will get proper access and can drill as needed. Additionally, you will want to make sure the threads are in good condition or risk blowing a plug out.

This may be more costly than you like, but the alternative is much more expensive.